# Is there are a resource handler or gantt chart creator tool for JIRA?

Tags: team-management, jira, gantt

I'm hoping someone has some experience on tools and/or better keywords to describe this problem:

1. I have JIRA system for developers where they provide estimates and track time completed. The estimate could be captured in a higher level tool, but the time track (effort applied) should not require double-entry and instead pull from JIRA.
2. There are multiple projects (up to 6 active over a pool of 20 projects) that all have pending work for the limited availability of developers (8 developers).
3. We might have to handle about 80 tasks a week we want to sort, prioritise, and schedule (an average task takes 2 to 4 hours to finish, we have 8 developers, so in the worst case - 4 hours per task - we have 80 tasks = (40 hrs / 4 hrs) * 8 developers).

Is it possible to manage the resources with deadline/timelines and start dates so the developers know what they should be working on across all projects?

Is there a tool that can be used with JIRA (or a plugin) that developers can update their progress (date, priority, etc.) with low effort?

Comment: Have you looked on Google?

Comment: Nice edits, @Zsolt!

Comment: Some keywords/features needed to solve this problem seem to be:  Critical Path, Resource Leveling or Auto-Scheduling (with Finish-to-Start,  Start-to-Start,  Start-to-Finish and  Finish-to-Finish versions).  Any I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using the [free add-on by Soyatec](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.soyatec.jira.plugins.jira-ganttchart-project). It produces Gantt charts that look similar to those from Microsoft Project. It allows you to set end dates and % done.

I haven't used it, however. You can find other alternatives at [Atlassian's marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?q=gantt%20chart&application=jira), such as [BigPicture](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1212259/bigpicture-project-management-ppm?hosting=cloud&tab=overview).

Comment: this sounds close, and helps to identify some keywords to look for, thanks!

Comment: This add-on does not appear to be free (any more?)

Answer (score 2):

There is a popular plugin for this purpose called [Gantt-Chart for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.polscheit.jira.plugins.gantt/server/overview). It give you a Gantt view of your issues.

Answer (score 2):

depending on what JIRA you use (server and cloud) there are a number of plugins available: [Gannt plugins](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?q=gannt)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** we highly discourage tool-specific questions in PMSE, as they're likely to not add much value 5 years from now.

Have you looked at **[Jira Structure](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.almworks.jira.structure)**? I'm leading a team with a similar structure and now that we (thankfully) moved into Jira, Structure is helping us a lot to prioritize and keep track of the progress in our tasks. Although it's not a proper Gantt Chart, it may fit your needs as well.

A short video explaining the idea can be found [HERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8e32sWFA-94).