# GANTT Charts in Jira

Tags: jira, gantt

Is there a way to generate GANTT charts directly from a 'basic software development' software project in Jira - or can I do something from a 'project management' project that links to software development project(s)?

Comment: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9189/is-there-are-a-resource-handler-or-gantt-chart-creator-tool-for-jira