# How can I show short tasks (less than 8 hours) in a JIRA Gantt chart?

Tags: jira, tasks, gantt

I recently installed a few apps (like BigPicture) which help you see the order of work of each programmer. The problem is that when I link some tasks with estimates less than one work day, the Gantt chart presents this task as a job that estimates one day.

How can I get the JIRA Gantt chart to show tasks of less than 8 hours?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there are a resource handler or gantt chart creator tool for JIRA?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9189/is-there-are-a-resource-handler-or-gantt-chart-creator-tool-for-jira)

Comment: Maybe it is to be a setting? I never seen this before - MSProject does not to be padding the tasks to days.

Comment: @tiagoperes The target question is related, but it's a different question than what the OP is asking. Linking it is good, but it doesn't appear to be a valid duplicate to me. Kudos for looking for duplicates, though!

Comment: @IssyForst There is no MS PROJECT in Jira

Comment: OP - are you trying to show dependency management?  If so, there are more effective ways of doing that in Jira that we can show you.

Comment: @Venture2099
With these logical cues, I will have the ability to show when each task is expected to begin or end.

Comment: @Venture2099
Like what ways?

Comment: I think it's a limitation on BigPicture and that it can't show tasks of less than a day. Maybe you could link those tasks without scheduling them automatically (i.e., keep the link end-to-start but have both tasks on the same day), if that is acceptable to you?

Answer (score -1):

The gantt charts like the one you use are not prepared to show that detail level for a reason, and is because it's a planning tool, and you don't make plans to say what are you going to do within a day, but to know if you are going to meet a deadline 3 months from today

Comment: This does not answer the question. I empathise with the sentiment.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, your answer is totally wrong.

You CAN make plans to say what you are going to do within a day in some projects. It's naïve to expect that every task for a project is going to have a minimum duration of one day, and it's inefficient to plan a whole day for something that can be completed in considerably less time.

Comment: Answers should answer the question, not debate with other answers.